# Model binding doesn't work for complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Here's the view I'm going to post:

```
@model WelcomeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignUp", "Member", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
{

    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SignUp.CompanyName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" }})
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SignUp.RegisteredNo, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
    ....
    <button type="submit" name="signup" class="btn">Register</button>
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WelcomeViewModel
{
    public SignInViewModel LogOn { get; set; }
    public SignUpViewModel SignUp { get; set; } 
}
```

Action method:

```
[HttpPost, AllowAnonymous, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> SignUp(SignUpViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("SignIn", new WelcomeViewModel { SignUp = model });

    // other code
    return View();
}
```

When I post the data, the model gets null. I know the inputs will be generated like:

```
<input id="SignUp_CompanyName" name="SignUp.CompanyName">
```

But the model binder accepts this:

```
<input id="SignUp_CompanyName" name="CompanyName">
```

Now I want to know how can I remove that prefix? I know I can explicitly add name for each input:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SignUp.CompanyName, new { Name = "CompanyName" })
```

but I want to do it in a strongly type way.

Comment: Either use the `[Bind]` attribute as per haim770's answer or post back `WelcomeViewModel` (not `SignUpViewModel`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way would be to apply the `[Bind]` attribute with its `Prefix` set to "SignUp":

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SignUp([Bind(Prefix="SignUp")] SignUpViewModel model)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)